# Not able to set state of new component when history.push() in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, oauth-2.0, react-hooks, fetch

I am trying to create a Login flow for a React front end using an OAuth2 authorization_code grant type. I have been able to get the user directed to the login page of auth server, which after a successful login redirects to my react front end at: `"http:localhost:3000/oauth_callback?code={auth_code}"`

This then renders the LoginCallback component which takes the auth_code value and sends a POST fetch request to get an access token, the response will look like this:

```
{
access_token: "640f3dce-11c6-45fe-8984-517ecce471ae", 
token_type: "bearer", 
expires_in: 37822, 
scope: "read"
}
```

After this is returned, I am trying to use history.push() to navigate the user to the Dashboard component, with the response data in the Dashboards state.

The problem I am having is that I cant set the state with the response of the fetch request, and because the LoginCallback component is redirected to from the auth server there is no parent component to send the state back up to.

LoginCallback:

```
import React, { FC, useEffect } from "react";
import { RouteComponentProps, useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import Dashboard from "./components/Dashboard";

const LoginCallback: FC<RouteComponentProps> = ({ location }) => {
  const history = useHistory();
  var response = {
    access_token: '',
    token_type: '',
    expires_in: 0,
    scope: ''
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    const code = (location.search.match(/code=([^&]+)/) || [])[1];
    const qParams = [
      `grant_type=authorization_code`,
      `scope=read`,
      `code=${code}`
    ].join("&");
    fetch(`http://localhost:9090/oauth/token?${qParams}`, {
      // credentials: "include",
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Basic Y2xpZW50MjpzZWNyZXQy'
      }
    })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => console.log(res))
      .then(res => JSON.stringify(res))
      .then(res => {
        console.log(`json.stringify(): ${JSON.stringify(res)}`);    // returns undefined
        console.log(`json.parse(): ${JSON.parse(res)}`);
        response = JSON.parse(res);                                 // returns syntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
        history.push({pathname: '/dashboard', state: {
          authenticated: true,
          access_token: response.access_token,
          token_type: response.token_type,
          expires_in: response.expires_in,
          scope: response.scope
        }});
      })
      .catch(console.error);
  }, []);
  return null;
};

export default LoginCallback;
```

Dashboard:

```
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import React, {useState} from 'react';

const Dashboard = () => {
    const [state, setAllValues] = useState({
        authenticated: false,
        access_token: '',
        token_type: '',
        expires_in: 0,
        scope: ''
     });
     const changeHandler = e => {
        setAllValues({...state, [e.target.name]: e.target.value})
     }

    return (
        <div>
            { state.authenticated ? <a href="/login">Login Here</a> : <a href="/logout">Logout</a> }
            <p> Dashboard </p>
            <p> Authenticated: {state.authenticated}</p>
            { state.authenticated ?
                <p> stored access token: {state.access_token} </p>
                            :
                null
            }
            
        </div>
    );
}

export default Dashboard;
```

Answer (score 1):

In your Dashboard component consider adding the following code

```
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

function Dashboard() {
  const { state } = useLocation();

  return <div>{JSON.stringify(state)}</div>;
}
```

I believe this will give you access to the state you passed in. If not share the relevant parts of your Dashboard code and we can have a look.

for your fetch call try:

```
fetch(`http://localhost:9090/oauth/token?${qParams}`, {
  // credentials: "include",
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Basic Y2xpZW50MjpzZWNyZXQy'
  }
})
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(response => {
    history.push({pathname: '/dashboard', state: {
      authenticated: true,
      access_token: response.access_token,
      token_type: response.token_type,
      expires_in: response.expires_in,
      scope: response.scope
    }});
  })
  .catch(console.error);
```

I find axios easier to use.

Comment: Thanks for the answer hapi, I have added the code for the dashboard to the question

Comment: Did you try console logging the state from `const { state } = useLocation();` ?

Comment: I have tried your solution, and it works well for redirecting the user to the Dashboard, but the values from the fetch response are still empty. It is definitely setting the state correctly, because authenticated = true now in the dashboard, so the response isnt being handled correctly in the fetch I think

Comment: That works! Thank you so much! Was the issue that I was passing res in so it was essentially bypassing the res.json() step?

Comment: you were converting the response to a string `.then(res => JSON.stringify(res))` I don't think you meant to do that. Axios is much easier to use than fetch IMO.  Glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 0):

`useHistory()` only works for those components which **HOC** is `BrowserRouter`

use This code where you import `Dashboard`

```js
 <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/dashboard" exact component={Dashboard} />
        </Switch>
 </BrowserRouter>
```